# Push Notifications in iOS 7> on a private server

Tags: java, ios, tomcat, apple-push-notifications

I would like to implement a server-side push notification service for iOS.

When the application goes to the Background I need to send notifications to the client for different events and if it's necessary to wake app the application.

Currently in my system I have Apache tomcat Server and what I'm interested in to have a kind of tutorial of how that could be implemented. Is it possible to use for instance web-sockets, or what kind of alternatives such as TCP sockets from JAVA?

I have found some stand alone services such as [AirNotifier](http://airnotifier.github.io/), and [EasyAPNs](http://www.easyapns.com/) but I would prefer not make complex my configuration by including more programming languages.

Thanks

Comment: To send a push notification you send a message directly to the APNS server at Apple. This message is done via an SSL connection, so you can not use websockets. How you apps communicates with your server to pass it push notification token is totally up to you.

Comment: You can't keep alive a background socket connection.
Here the supported background tasks:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html
However there are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Domenico Vacchiano: In the documentation you sent it says:

Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.

So this socket could be web-socket?

Comment: @rckoenes: I'm not interested in into using the APNS server from apple but just a communication channel between my app and my server directly. Is that not possible?

Comment: Keep a socket open in your while it is in the background is not allowed. Only allowed for VOIP, music players, accessory or location based are allowed to in the background. Apple does this to save battery. APNS is your best solution to make sure that your app is draining the battery.

Comment: Is it possible to have my own APNS server, without using the systems of apple?